# Magento pagination query different to list.phtml file collection

Tags: magento-1.7, pagination

I have tried to filter the magento product result according to stock and all color and etc. so i have wrote some query, but instead of query my pagination page numbers are different, when i debug this then i got that my pagination 'pager.phtml' file load any other collection from any where but not loading my custom filter collection so how i can load my custom collection in pager.html file..

```
$_productCollection = $_productCollection->joinField('is_in_stock',
                         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                         'is_in_stock',
                         'product_id=entity_id',
                         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                         'left')->addAttributeToSort('updated_at','desc')->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('gt' => 0));
```

abover query return 134 results but below file query retrieving 230 results /app/design/frontend/default/MAG090181/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
$this->getCollection()
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please share your code and file location?

Comment: @Abdul ,yeah sure ..

Comment: Please add your code in function prepareProductCollection() at location Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Abdul . But i have found another and good way by which i did that,  below is the code

```
$this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar_bottom.phtml')->setCollection($_productCollection)->toHtml();
```